# Can't update packages via pip in google colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, tflite

I'm trying to run a python deep learning model with google colab, and I'm still after installing **tflite-model-maker** and **tflite-support** with this code

```
!pip install -q tflite-model-maker
!pip install -q tflite-support
```

this error:

```py
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
xarray 2022.12.0 requires packaging>=21.3, but you have packaging 20.9 which is incompatible.
```

I have updated the packaging with `!pip install --upgrade packaging` in the previous step but it didn't help.

Comment: try with `!pip uninstall -y packaging` and `!pip install packaging`. And after that you can try `!pip install -q tflite-model-maker` and `!pip install -q tflite-support`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
`!pip install -q xarray==0.18.2 packaging==21.3 tflite-model-maker tflite-support`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! I only downgraded xarray_einstats to 0.4.0 cause it wasn't compatible with the old xarray version, and it works now. So the whole command is: `!pip install -q xarray==0.18.2 xarray-einstats==0.4.0 packaging==21.3 tflite-model-maker tflite-support`